# What is the sign of a cycle?

Tags: group-theory

I am not sure what the "sign" of a cycle means.  I believe it has something to do with parity, but I am not sure. For example, say I have the cycle $\tau = (2,3,4,5,7)$, what would be its sign?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_a_permutation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sign $s(\pi)$ of a permutation $\pi$ is either $1$ or $-1$, depending on whether the permutation is *even* or *odd*, i.e. whether $\pi$ is produced by composition an even or odd number $n$ of transpositions: $s(\pi) = (-1)^n$.

A cycle of length $n$ is produced by $n-1$ transpositions, hence it has the sign $(-1)^{n-1}$.

Comment: Okay, so would the sign of (1,2,3) and (5,9,2) be -1.  What about (1,3)(5,6)(7,6)?

Comment: No, the signs of $(1 \ 2 \ 3)$ and $(5 \ 9 \ 2)$ are both $1$ because both can be written as a product of two (an even number) of transpositions: $(1 \ 2 \ 3) = (1 \ 3)(1 \ 2)$ and $(5 \ 9 \ 2)=(5 \ 2) (5 \ 9)$. Also, as @McFry noted, a cycle of length $n$ (in this case $n=3$) is a product of $n-1$ transpositions so has sign $(-1)^{n-1}$ (in this case $(-1)^{3-1}=(-1)^2=1$).

Comment: I understand what a transposition is now. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The sign of a cycle of length $n$ is the number of transpositions needed to convert the permutation $12\cdots n$ into the given cycle modulo $2$.

If the number of transpositions is even, the sign is $1$, otherwise it is $-1$.

For example $1324$ has sign $-1$ , but $23451$ has sign $1$.

As the example shows, the elements need not be $12\cdots n$. In this case, the identical permutation is given by the strictly increasing permutation. Again, you only need to find out the number of transpositions needed to convert this permutation to the given cycle.

Comment: $(2143)$ has sign $-1$ too.

Comment: $(2143)$ is not a $4$-cycle. But why has it sign $-1$ ? We get from $1234$ to $2143$ via the transpositions $12$ and $34$.

Comment: I see. Didn't get you were using a non-standard notation.